# Azure app service deploy to multiple instances with auto scaling

Tags: azure, deployment, azure-web-app-service

I've been trying to figure out the following: Do I need to disable auto scaling during a deploy when I'm using slots?

My Azure setup is:

- One production site with auto scaling enabled
- One staging slot
- DevOps release going to the staging slot, which is then swapped with production

My thoughts are: what if the production site has spawned 3 instances, and I then start to release (to the 3 staging slot instances), but during this process, a scale out or in occurs, either adding or removing an instance. Would my release break in the middle or be rolled back?

Answer (score 0):

As the [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/app-service/deploy-staging-slots#which-settings-are-swapped) suggests scale settings is not swapped. The staging slot you have would be independent than production slot. And swap during scale in/out would not break the release. It will wait and adapt appropriately for the target slot to the scale need as per the scale rule and resource demand seamlessly.